# What is an example of a transparent matter with refractive index less than 1?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, speed-of-light, refraction

I am looking for a concrete example of a transparent matter and wave length of a radiation at which the [refractive index of the matter is less than 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refractive_index#Refractive_index_below_unity) (if they exist, of course).

There are several similar questions around, e.g. [Medium with refractive index less than unity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/232149/) however I have not found an answer to my question.

Comment: How transparent would it need to be? Many such materials are lossy, but if they’re thin, then considerable light would transmit. And relatedly, are you concerned only about the real part of n being less than one? Finally, are you looking for any example to provide a proof of concept for yourself, or are you interested in a particular frequency band?

Comment: @Gilbert: I mean that $n$ should be real .

Comment: You may find an answer to your question here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/353306/can-a-medium-can-have-refractive-index-less-than-the-reference-refractive-index